# Apache how to find cause of 404 with rewriterule ignored

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, mod-rewrite

So I have this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (da-dk)/(.*)(/|\.php)$
RewriteRule ^(da-dk)/(.*)(/|\.php)$ /$2$3 [L]
```

But for some reasons example.com/da-dk/ gives "404 - not found"

I would like to try understand why apache reaches that conclusion - i.e. what rules it encountered and followed

Comment: This rule is presumably in the root `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other rules? How do you expect a request for `/da-dk/` to be processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is in the root `.htaccess` file...

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(da-dk)/(.*)(/|\.php)$ /$2$3 [L]
> ```

A request for `/da-dk/` (which matches against the URL-path `da-dk/`) does not match the regex `^(da-dk)/(.*)(/|\.php)$` so this rule is not processed/followed.

So, unless you have other rules that match this request then *no* rules are followed, hence the 404. (As for what rules are "encountered", well, all the other rules you have are *encountered*.)

Incidentally, the preceding *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) is entirely superfluous here and should be removed.  It's not doing anything more that what the `RewriteRule` *pattern* has already established.

Specifically, this rule (regex) would match URLs of the form:

- `/da-dk/.php`
- `/da-dk/<foo>/`
- `/da-dk/<foo>.php`
- `/da-dk/<foo>/<bar>/<baz>/`
- `/da-dk/<foo>/<bar>/<baz>.php`

It does not match:

- `/da-dk/<foo>`
- `/da-dk/`

This rule simply removes the `/da-dk` prefix on the requested URL (presumably in the *hope* that the rewritten URL matches a filesystem directory or file).

If `/da-dk/` should be rewritten back to the root then the above rule can be modified to allow for this (in the process, it can also be simplified slightly). For example, try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^da-dk/(.+(/|\.php))?$ /$1 [L]
```

Here, the part of the URL-path after `da-dk/` is made *optional*. (In this case, the `$1` backreference is effectively *empty*.)

By changing the quantifier from `*` to `+` this also avoids matching the (nonsense) URL `/da-dk/.php`.

No need to *capture* the `da-dk` part (first path segment), since this is not being used in the *substitution* string (2nd argument).

The `$1` backreference now contains the entire URL-path after the `da-dk/` prefix. (No need for `$2` and `$3` as you had originally.)

Comment: I think I will mark this an answer and maybe create a new SO. I am still getting 404. (I had tried some different rewriterules and always got 404. But your rewriterule is better then those I tried. So under all circumstances I had a bug there.) I had hoped for Apache logging that could tell me at what lines rules were followed.